# How to create a pointer to only the first letter of a string

Tags: c, string, char, strcmp

I'm trying to use strcmp() to compare to the first letter of the string line (which should be "V") with the letter "V" in c.

I've tried several different methods of trying to create a pointer to only the first letter of the string in order to use to compare.  My latest solution seemed to work better but is adding some string of letters after the initial assignment.

```c
    printf("test:%c ", line[1]);
    char* ch;
    ch[0] = line[1];
    printf("ch is: %s\n", ch);  
    printf("strcmp result: %d\n", strcmp(ch, "V"));
```

line is already initialized as a long string (read from a file).
The second letter of line is "V", so I would expect ch = "V".  However, these results show up:

test:V

ch is: VL?[?

strcmp result: 76

Similarly, this code:

```c
    char ch[1];
    ch[0] = line[1];
    printf("ch is: %s\n", ch);
    printf("strcmp result: %d\n", strcmp(ch, "V"));
```

provides this incorrect answer:
test:V

ch is: V?

strcmp result: 133

Wondering why those extra letters show up in ch, and if there's a better way to do this in general.  My entire program relies on reading and comparing certain letters in the string line so this is an essential part of it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot compare a pointer-to-character as a string. **It's not nul-terminated** (which is why you get additional characters) Now you can fudge it by using a 2-character array with the last character `0`, e.g. `char ch[2] = "";` and then use `ch[0] = line[1];` and `strcmp(ch, "V")`. ALL *string* functions in C require a *nul-terminated* string as their argument.

Comment: What is ch pointing at?

Comment: In the shown code, ch is an uninitialized pointer.   That is, it holds a pointer, but was never told what to point to.   So, it might point to NULL, and it might point to some random address.   When you set `ch[0] = line[1]`, then you're writing the character at `line[1]` to wherever `ch` happens to be pointing.   If `ch` happens to be a valid address, then this means you're _scribbling_ over some other data that might be important to someone else.  If it's not a valid address, you get a segmentation fault...

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with c strings -- learn what a character holds vs what a character pointer holds, learn the syntax  `"V"` vs`'V'`, and learn what null-termination means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you're getting is because `ch` does not point to a null terminated string.

In the first case:

```
char* ch;
ch[0] = line[1];
```

The pointer `ch` hasn't been initialized, but you then dereference the pointer (implicitly via the array subscript operator `[]`) in an attempt to write to it.  Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in your case gives unexpected output.

Similarly for the second case:

```
char ch[1];
ch[0] = line[1];
```

Here `ch` is an array of size 1 and you assign a value to that member.  But then you pass `ch` to `strcmp` which expects a null terminated string.  Since the array only contains 1 element, there is no space for the null terminator.  As a result the `strcmp` reads past the end of the array looking for one.  Reading past the end of an array also invokes undefined behavior.

To do a proper string comparison, the array must have room for the string in question which means the size must be at least 2:

```
char ch[2];
ch[0] = line[1];
ch[1] = 0;
```

However, your goal is not to compare strings.  You want to compare a single character instead.  To do that, just use single quotes to denote a character constant and compare that directly against the element in question:

```
printf("test:%c ", line[1]);
printf("strcmp result: %d\n", (line[1] == 'V'));
```